# Know which column is currently sorted in Bootstrap DataTables

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there any way to know which column was clicked/sorted in Bootstrap DataTables?

I need to export/Print datatables in my project and maintain the sorting choice.

It would be great to set a global JS var to whatever column name was clicked/sorted so I can pass that via JS to my controller in .net/MVC5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Must use:

```
    var oTable = $('#YOURTABLENAME').dataTable();
    var oSettings = oTable.fnSettings();
```

This gets the settings for the DataTable.
Then you can use something like:

```
 sortEventFired(oSettings.aaSorting);
```

Because aaSorting gives you the column index and direction

example: 1,asc

[Look here](http://www.datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/dt_events.html)

[and here under fnSettings](http://legacy.datatables.net/ref)

[and finally here](http://datatables.net/docs/DataTables/1.9.0/DataTable.models.oSettings.html)